# Twitter integration:consumer key/secret pair already set

Tags: twitter, key, integration, twitter4j

Trying to integrate my webapp with Twitter using [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) lib.
I have registered my app on twitter site and got `Consumer key` and `Consumer secret` values.
Nothing special,standard `OAuth` step.

**code:**

```
public class TwitterService {
    private final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx";
    private final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "yyy";

    public String fav() {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
...
```

**exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.
```

I have no more configuration for `key` and `secret`,any `.properties` or other file.

**EDIT:**

commenting line `twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);` causes exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looking at both the code and documentation, it looks like your method of instantiating a `Twitter` instance is not recommended. If you want to supply configuration programmatically (and not use properties), it looks like you need to supply a `Configuration` to the `TwitterFactory`.

```
...
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
Configuration configuration = builder.build();
TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
...
```

The singleton provided by a factory that hasn't been supplied with a configuration defaults to using an `Authorization` implementation backed by a `PropertyConfiguration` configuration. If there is no properties file, it *looks* like it shouldn't instantiate an `OAuthAuthorization` auth, which is what would cause the exception you're seeing. But `PropertyConfiguration` does search the entire `CLASSPATH` for an appropriate properties file, so maybe you overlooked one. You could try logging the key and secret right after getting the `Twitter` instance to see what they *are* set to:

```
System.out.println("key:" + twitter.getConfiguration().getOAuthConsumerKey());
System.out.println("secret: " + twitter.getConfiguration().getOAuthConsumerSecret());
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you're setting the private final variables and then twitter.setOAuthConsumer() is trying to do the same.  You should only need one or the other.  Have you tried commenting out the twitter.setOAuthConsumer() line?

The [Docs](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth) explain the 'preferred' way to do set these.

Comment: see me EDIT section,please.Got exception if commented