# Why occure consumer key/secret pair already set, IllegalStateException in my android App?

Tags: android, twitter

I am Integrating Twitter in my android app but I got following exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterBaseImpl.java:264)
at com.flashdeal.twitter.TwitterApp.configureToken(TwitterApp.java:72)
at com.flashdeal.twitter.TwitterApp.access$7(TwitterApp.java:70)
at com.flashdeal.twitter.TwitterApp$3.run(TwitterApp.java:150)
```

I have change my consuer and secret key as well but unable to login got still got this exception My code is here:-

```
    public class TwitterApp {
    private Twitter mTwitter;
    private TwitterSession mSession;
    private AccessToken mAccessToken;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
    private String mConsumerKey;
    private String mSecretKey;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
    private TwDialogListener mListener;
    private Context context;

    public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect";
    private static final String TAG = "TwitterApp";

    public TwitterApp(Context context, String consumerKey, String secretKey) {
        this.context    = context;

        mTwitter        = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        mSession        = new TwitterSession(context);
        mProgressDlg    = new ProgressDialog(context);

        mProgressDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mConsumerKey    = consumerKey;
        mSecretKey      = secretKey;

        mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
        mHttpOauthprovider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                     "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                     "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

        mAccessToken    = mSession.getAccessToken();

        configureToken();
    }

    public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void configureToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);

            mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasAccessToken() {
        return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mSession.resetAccessToken();

            mAccessToken = null;
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mSession.getUsername();
    }
    public long getUserId() {
        return mSession.getAccessToken().getUserId();
    }
    public String getScreen_name() {
        return mSession.getAccessToken().getScreenName();
    }
    public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
        try {
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void authorize() {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing ...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String authUrl = "";
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);    

                    what = 0;

                    Log.d(TAG, "Request token url " + authUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get request token");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void processToken(String callbackUrl)  {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, verifier);

                    mAccessToken = new AccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(), mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                    configureToken();

                    User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();

                    mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting access token");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
        String verifier  = "";

        try {
            callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "https");

            URL url         = new URL(callbackUrl);
            String query    = url.getQuery();

            String array[]  = query.split("&");

            for (String parameter : array) {
                 String v[] = parameter.split("=");

                 if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                     verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                     break;
                 }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return verifier;
    }

    private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
        final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String value) {
                processToken(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String value) {
                mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
            }
        };

        new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            if (msg.what == 1) {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
                else
                    mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
            } else {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
                else
                    mListener.onComplete("");
            }
        }
    };

    public interface TwDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(String value);       

        public void onError(String value);
    }
}
```

I am using following jar files:-

1- twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

And call it from my Activity As bellow:-

```
  mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, AppConstant.CONSUMER_KEY,
                AppConstant.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);
```

Please anyone guide me thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505862/twitter-integrationconsumer-key-secret-pair-already-set

Comment: If @basilisk answer works for you, please post an answer and mark it as close, this question still OPEN