# java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, oauth

I'm using Spring framework to login with twitter into my website, I'm actually learning from [this tutorial](http://tech-read.com/2011/09/17/intergrating-twitter-oauth-using-javaspringtwitter4j/).

So i followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505862/twitter-integrationconsumer-key-secret-pair-already-set) and changed my source accordingly below:

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    private final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxx";
    private final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxx";

    ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

    Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build();

    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

    @Autowired
    private MyAccessToken accestoken;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String printWelcome(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) {

        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        RequestToken requestToken;
        try {

            String callbackURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cwitter/callback";
            System.out.println("callback url is " + callbackURL);
             requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL);
             String token = requestToken.getToken();
            String tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
            accestoken.setTokensecret(tokenSecret);
            accestoken.setToken(token);
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
            request.setAttribute("authUrl", authUrl);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/test1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test1(@PathVariable String username,@RequestParam("userdetails") String userDetails,ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("test1 " + username + "\t" + userDetails);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callback",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test1(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model){
         Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");
        System.out.println(twitter);
        RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("requestToken");
        String verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
        Enumeration attrList = request.getSession().getAttributeNames();
        while(attrList.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute((String)attrList.nextElement()));
        }
        try {
           System.out.println(twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier));
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
//          twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

            User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
            model.addAttribute("message", user.getName());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

So, I simply tried to run all my project but it says the following logs:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/cwitter] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
    at com.common.controller.HelloController.printWelcome(HelloController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let know, What's wrong here?

**Any kind of help would be appreciated!!**

Comment: is it supposed to say "cwitter"? Isnt that a typo for "twitter"?